# Activley check if process is open?

Tags: python

I have been trying to get my code to check if a process is open and then if it is do something.

I got that to part to work but i am struggling to get the program to stop if the process stops suddenly while the code is already running.

Here is code so far:

```
import psutil
process_name = "firefox" 
for proc in psutil.process_iter(): 
    process = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
    pname = process.name()
while pname == process_name:
    print ("have")
    if pname != process_name:
       break
```

everything works fine except for this line inside the while loop

```
if pname != process_name:
    break
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if process is active inside the while loop. I add a sleep of 1 second also.

```
import psutil
import time

def check(pname):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(): 
        process = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
        pname.append(process.name())
    return pname

process_name = "firefox"
pname = check([])
while process_name in pname:
    print("have")
    pname = check([])
    time.sleep(1)
```